# How can I get value from current stream in RxJS?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have `this.selectedFilters$` - this value should be change when `this.filter$` (initalization) or `this.newFilter$` emit any value. That's why I used merge.

So when `this.newFilter$` emit any value I need to update **CURRENT OBJECT** based on data from `this.newFilter$`. However I've no idea how can I get that current value properly from `this.selectedFilters$` I was trying to use `withLatestFrom(this.selectedFilters$)` but compilator will fails since at the beginning `this.selectedFilters$` is just simply empty before initalization.

For now I solved it by saving current value to local variable `this.currentFilters` using `tap()` - but I know that is bad practice, at least it works for now... How can I solve it better?

```
  this.selectedFilters$ = merge(
      this.filter$.pipe(
        switchMap((allFilters) => {
          return of({
            itemId: allFilters[0].itemId,
            filterOptions: this.getDefaultFilterOptions(allFilters)
          });
        }),
      ),
      this.newFilter$.pipe(
        switchMap((newFilter: FilterOption) => {
          return of(this.getNewFilterOptions(newFilter, this.currentFilters));
        }),
      )
    ).pipe(tap((filters) => this.currentFilters = filters));
  }

  // LESS IMPORTANT CODE BELOW...

  private getNewFilterOptions(newFilter: FilterOption, currentFilters: ItemFilter): ItemFilter {
    const changedFilter = currentFilters.filterOptions.findIndex(f => f.filterId === newFilter.filterId);
    currentFilters.filterOptions[changedFilter] = newFilter;

    return currentFilters;
  }

  private getDefaultFilterOptions(filters: ItemFilter[]): FilterOption[] {
    return filters.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item.filterOptions[0]), []);
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with `withLatestFrom`

Comment: When `withLatestFrom(this.selectedFilters$)` I have an error: `core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Comment: Just define the `this.selectedFilters$` chain before the chain with `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: I expected that first part of `merge` did it Anyway `selectedFilters$ = of({})` doesn't work properly